# autofs ssh fuse and permissions issue

Tags: linux, ssh, centos6, autofs, fuse

I have a mounted remote backup space on a Centos 6 to perform remote backups..which are doing fine.. without issues

```
My /etc/auto.master file:
/- /etc/auto.mymount uid=0,gid=0,--ghost

My /etc/auto.mymount file:
/mnt/backup  -fstype=fuse,rw,allow_other,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa :sshfs\#user@of-storage box\:/
```

My problem is, that backup rotation fails, even allow_other has been declared

Cron:

```
30 3 */2 * * root find /mnt/backup/backup_space/* -type d -ctime +5 -delete
```

Error:

```
find: cannot delete `/mnt/backup/backup_space/2019-04-05': Operation not permitted
```

Still cannot track the issue down, since autofs, fuse have been installed as root user. Any help for me?